# Raspberry Pi 3 (Raspbian) programatically accessing a USB drive: best way to do this?

Tags: raspbian, raspberry-pi3, usb-drive

I'm running Raspbian 1.0, v9/15 on an RP3. I'm working on an application that will access a dedicated USB flash drive to store collected data. The static path to write the data is "/media/user/kingston". This works great unless I have a system crash at which point the owner and group for "/media/user/kingston" are changed to root, and the mount point for the flash drive now is now changed to "/media/user/kingston1" which (clearly) does not work with the static path defined in my application. Is there a standard dynamic path option that is available for this device and OS? Thanks in advance...

**Update:** Based on BJ Black's advice, this is what I added to fstab after creating a directory named /usb at the root of the filesystem,

```
/dev/sda1  /usb  vfat noatime,nofail,user,rw,exec,umask=000   0  3
```

The advantages are,
1) allows bootup even when no USB drive is inserted,
2) allows any usb storage device to be used here.

Disadvantage is that the system must be powered down (or drive umounted) before flash drive is removed otherwise bad things happen, (I tried this). Question: Is there anything that I can do to reduce the "bad things" in the event that someone pulls out the usb while it is still mounted? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hopefully nobody tells you to mount the drive with the sync option; it will cause seriously huge writes to the flash and wear it out fast (though it will reduce the possibility of file system corruption on power outage or similar).  If you have some RAM to spare and can live with some loss of data on outage, I'd actually log to RAM disk and use rsync or logrotate to push it out to flash periodically.  Or you can use a low-profile USB stick (such as http://p3e9.qr.ai) to make it harder to remove and reduce the possibility your users will be dumb :-)

Comment: This will be at a remote location, Raspberry Pi connected to a camera board & solar panel and rechargeable battery. No keyboard or monitor. Techs will visit the site every few weeks, disconnect power, remove USB, insert new USB, reconnect power.

Comment: Hmm.  Is it worth putting on a status LED or two on there to make sure that the device is in good shape then?  Otherwise I'd say go with a log-structured filesystem like f2fs as a happy medium.  See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/F2FS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, I tend to prefer using a hard mount point for this kind of thing.  There are possibly some neat tricks in /sys (or by using a grep against the output of mount(1) or /proc/mounts), but they'll fail as soon as you change out your Kingston stick for some other vendor (yuck).

Have a look at [this link](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=91677) to better understand what's automounting your usb stick and how to shut that mechanism off.

As for mounting in a permanent place, I'd try either:

1. Create a mount point (say /data) and put an entry in fstab(5) so it gets mounted automatically on boot.
2. Same as 1, but use the noauto and user and do an explicit call to mount(1) from your application, or...
3. Install autofs and put an entry in auto.misc to automount the device (probably /dev/sda1) on use.  Then symlink /data -> /misc/data.

Of these, I like option 3 the best, as the stick will unmount automatically when idle.  Then your application need only double-check that the path is writable beforehand.

Also be super-careful on writes, as cheapie USB sticks tend to erase in large blocks and their wear levelling is weak at best (so both small random writes and large writes tend to wear the flash fast).  Using f2fs or careful write buffering helps (and the noatime option on mount helps).  And don't call fsync() all the time in your app!